# Can not download e-books with Amazon kindle shop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, kindle

I cannot download e-books through amazon kindle shop.I call the supporter and he said its' a network issue and my internet ISP has bad connection with Amazon server. However, I can connect the Amazon Server using my PC or IPad. It really confused me a lot.

However, I can download e-books through the shop frequently under my IPhone 4G Hotpoint WIFI.

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user's ISP is to blame.

Comment: @Ramhound I think it is not just ISP responsibility，Amazon has also duty to solve this issue，Why other big company's product can be used frequently? Amazon should give users solutions to resolve this issue.

Comment: It does not really matter which party is at fault.  Your question is out of scope here at Superuser.  You either are asking a question about an iPhone which is specifically out of scope here at Superuser or your problem is caused by your ISP/Amazon which can only be fixed by your ISP/Amazon.

Comment: I resolved this issue now. Fow now,  I can download e-book through the Amazon kindle shop by set my Router's channel under 10.

Comment: Changing the frequency of the access point indicates you simply have a great deal of wireless signal interference and it has nothing do with Amazon specifically (nor does it have to do with you ISP if changing the channel resolves the problem).

Comment: @Ramhound yeah, it's so weird. When I calling the supporter, He said it's just about my ISP and I cannot connect to the amazon server.However I can get connection to amazon sever from other product.Another supporter told me that kindle doesn't support channel over 10.So I tried this way and worked.

Comment: Amazon support isn't qualified to determine if your problem is caused by your ISPs connection to Amazon or you network configuration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems, your ISP is definitely facing problems connecting Amazon servers. There may also possibility of problems from Amazon servers or their load balancers. Myself also faces the same problem sometimes.

> re-Check connecting to another hotspot from another ISP. This may
>   solve problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It just makes me unfriendly experience.